# Regular Bootstrap versus Bootstrap/theme in Bootstrap-sass 3.1.1 gem rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a little confused as to versions of Bootstrap and how to enable them in Rails.

After installing bootstrap-sass gem (3.1.1) and writing `@import "bootstrap"` into my `application.css.scss` folder, the styles on my views seem to default to bootstrap version 2.3.2, using classes like "hero-unit" instead of "jumbotron" (jumbotron only available in the latest bootstrap 3.1.1). Why does that happen?

Why do I have to `@import "bootstrap/theme` to make "jumbotron" work when in fact, "jumbotron" seems to be just part of 3.1.1, as shown by http://getbootstrap.com/components/ ?

Or am I just confused? Is "hero-unit" a part of every regular bootstrap file and "jumbotron" only comes when you enable "bootstrap/theme"?

Comment: but you wrote the HTML with the classes in it, no?

Comment: @sevenseacat yeah I wrote them in HTML to test them out. Only when I enable import "bootstrap/theme", does jumbotron work. I was just confused because I thought 3.1.1 just defaults to jumbotron and other features shown on getbootstrap.com/components without the "theme" part of it

Comment: `hero-unit` is gone in Bootstrap v3; it got renamed to `jumbotron`.

Comment: @cvrebert right, I get that. But I am wondering as to why `hero-unit` even works when I use `@import "bootstrap"` using my bootstrap-sass gem (3.1.1), and then `jumbotron` only kicks in when I specify `@import "bootstrap/theme"`